# how to implement soft deletes

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Can anyone tell me what would be a good way to implement soft deletes? I can have a `deleted` property in my class, but my question is how to easily ignore instances which have `deleted = true` in my searches, listings and so on.

So, rather than saying `Domain.findByDeleted(true)` just get `Domain.list()` to ignore deleted instances, rather than saying `Domain.findByPropertyAndDeleted('property', true)` just say `Domain.findByProperty('property')`.

Is there a nice way of doing this?

Comment: This should help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768534/grails-update-instead-of-delete/8768728

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using a [named query](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) for this. Something like

```
static namedQueries = {
    notDeleted {
        ne 'deleted', true
    }
}
```

which you could use like `Domain.notDeleted.list()` or `Domain.notDeleted.findByProperty(value)`

Answer (score 1):

The [hibernate filter plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) can automatically add the predicate `deleted = false` to every query that is performed for a particular domain class. However, my testing indicated that this plugin does not work with Grails 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

We're used to override `list()`, `get()` and some more methods of domain classes. Now we can use syntax like `A.delete(log: true)`

On bootstrap, we do:

```
grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { GrailsDomainClass domainClassInfo ->
    def oldGormDelete = domainClassInfo.metaClass.getMetaMethod('delete', [] as Class[])
    assert oldGormDelete
    domainClassInfo.metaClass.delete = { Map params ->
        ...
        def result = oldGormDelete.invoke(delegate)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the second time I've come across this strategy. I'm not too familiar with grails meta programming, Could you please explain what is going on here, invoking delegate?

Comment: I'm using Groovy metaprogramming (see http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses, "ExpandoMetaClass" section). In Class' `metaClass` property I'm assigning closures to be called instead of certain method signatures, in the example - static `delete(Map params)` method. `delegate` is a Groovy keyword like `this` and `owner`, meaning the object the closure is called as a method of - see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures. `invoke()` is, er, `Closure`'s method to execute it with a given `this` and given list of arguments - the parameters after first one will be used as call arguments.